# Email display issues

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, display

I created emails with html and css, the email is displaying very fine on gmail and hotmail but the images are not showing properly on yahoo, I have tried solving this but do not know what to do.

[image]

Below are the codes for the affected section

```html
<tr>
    <td align="left" style="padding:30px 0 8px 0;font-family:Montserrat,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:20px;line-height:26px;font-weight:bold">Featured Movies<br />
    <span style="font-size:16px;"><em>For relaxation, we&rsquo;ve got movies to keep you entertained during the weekend.</em></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: white; padding:">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th align="center" valign="top" width="320">
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:separate;max-width:100%" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top"><a data-saferedirecturl="https://hotels.ng/" href="https://hotels.ng/hotel/26241-ibis-lagos-airport-lagos?utm_source=hng02082022&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=html-deals&amp;utm_content=hi-here-are-some-safe-hotels-to-check-in-to-now?&amp;utm_term=control" style="display:block" target="_blank"><img alt="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" src="https://info.hotels.ng/uploads/1662394368.PNG" style="object-fit: cover;display: block; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 8px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 296px; height: 206px !important;" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:15px 0 4px 0;font-family:Montserrat,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:22px;font-weight:bold;color:#333333" valign="top">Thor: Love and Thunder</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:0 0 0px 0;font-family:Montserrat,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;font-weight:normal;color:#6b6b6b" valign="top">Love and Thunder is a 2022 American superhero film based on Marvel Comics featuring the character Thor, produced by Marvel Studios. It is the sequel to Thor: Ragnarok and the 29th film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe and it&#39;s in cinemas</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </th>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <th align="center" valign="top" width="320">
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="padding-bottom: 0px; border-collapse:separate;max-width:100%" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top"><a data-saferedirecturl="https://hotels.ng/" href="https://hotels.ng/hotel/26241-ibis-lagos-airport-lagos?utm_source=hng02082022&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=html-deals&amp;utm_content=hi-here-are-some-safe-hotels-to-check-in-to-now?&amp;utm_term=control" style="display:block" target="_blank"><img alt="" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" src="https://info.hotels.ng/uploads/1662393994.png" style="object-fit: cover;display: block; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 8px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 296px; height: 206px !important;" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:15px 0 4px 0;font-family:Montserrat,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#333333" valign="top">Beast</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:0 0 0px 0;font-family:Montserrat,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;font-weight:normal;color:#6b6b6b" valign="top">Beast is a 2022 American survival thriller film directed by Baltasar Korm&aacute;kur from a screenplay by Ryan Engle, based on a story by Jaime Primak Sullivan. The film stars Idris Elba, Iyana Halley, Leah Sava Jeffries, and Sharlto Copley and it&#39;s on cinema</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I would avoid object-fit: cover on emails, this is fairly new css for an email app to handle and most won't like Outlook etc. Ideally images should be specified simply:

display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;

https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-object-fit/

Comment: See here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/object-fit/ Yahoo is not supported.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasJames that actually answered my question